# Can someone explain this javascript memory leak scenario to me

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/ On this link, Listing 5 describes a situation where obj is a reference to a dom element, and the dom element has a reference to obj, and therefore causes a memory leak. I'm struggling to see what in the code makes the DOM element have a reference to obj.
Could someone explain it to me?

***Taken from the page:***

In Listing 5 you see a closure in which a JavaScript object (obj) contains a reference to a DOM object (referenced by the id "element"). The DOM element, in turn, has a reference to the JavaScript obj. The resulting circular reference between the JavaScript object and the DOM object causes a memory leak.

Listing 5. Event handling memory leak pattern

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Program to illustrate memory leak via closure");
window.onload=function outerFunction(){
    var obj = document.getElementById("element");
    obj.onclick=function innerFunction(){
    alert("Hi! I will leak");
    };
    obj.bigString=new Array(1000).join(new Array(2000).join("XXXXX"));
    // This is used to make the leak significant
};
</script>
<button id="element">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the memory leak exists because of the circular reference between *obj* and *onclick*.

Normally, after the execution of *onload*, all variables in its scope will be garbage collected and erased.
In javascript however, a function-scope is not always deleted after the execution. This is called **closures**.

For example, if an outer object references something in this scope. In this case onclick *references outerFunction* and *outerFunction* is referenced by *obj*

[image: illustration of a closure-caused memory leak]

If obj would be set to *null*, there would not be a reference to something within the *onload-scope*.

One can argue that the reference ist still to *outerFunction*, which is correct. But outerFunction is not bound anymore to the *onload-scope*, making this scope valid to be cleaned by the garbage collector.