# Does jQuery's event-handling cause memory leaks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I was reading up on *memory leaks* because my site's memory keeps piling up, when I came across this article from IBM:

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/#N10116

> **Closures and circular references**
>   In Listing 5 you see a closure in which a JavaScript object (obj) contains a reference to a DOM object (referenced by the id "element"). The DOM element, in turn, has a reference to the JavaScript obj. The resulting circular reference between the JavaScript object and the DOM object causes a memory leak.
>
> Listing 5. Event handling memory leak pattern:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Program to illustrate memory leak via closure");
window.onload=function outerFunction(){
    var obj = document.getElementById("element");
    obj.onclick=function innerFunction(){
    alert("Hi! I will leak");
    };
    obj.bigString=new Array(1000).join(new Array(2000).join("XXXXX"));
    // This is used to make the leak significant
};
</script>
<button id="element">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

One solution they give, is setting `obj` to `null` at the end of the `onload-function`.

*(see [Can someone explain this javascript memory leak scenario to me](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15496585/3407923) for an explanation on why this creates a memory leak)*

---

Now, I may very well be missing something here, hence the question, but isn't this also what happens when you add a jQuery event-handler:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $("element").on("click",function() {
        alert("Will this also leak?");
    });
};
</script>
<button id="element">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

You have basically the same `click-handler` inside the `window.load-function`, right?
I know you don't create a `var obj`, but the code still creates a *jQuery object*.

Am I really adding a memory-leak with every jQuery-handler I add?
Or am I completely misunderstanding these two situations?

Comment: Don´t have an answer but would recommend reading https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/memory-diagnosis?hl=en and https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/heap-profiling

Comment: in their example, it is a leak, but it'd only occur ONCE. a memory leak is only an issue if it occurs repeatedly. e.g if you have (say) a web-based chat, and your method of updating the message windows causes a leak, then yes, you'd eventually run out of memory as messages come in. but if a leakable event only occurs ONCE in the lifetime of the page, then it won't be much of an issue.

Comment: That article is from 2007. Forget it. Browsers that had issues with circular references crossing the DOM boundary are dead for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was reading up on memory leaks when I came across this article from IBM: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-memleak/#N10116

That article is from 2007. Forget it. Browsers that had issues with circular references crossing the DOM boundary are dead for a long time.

> I know you don't create a `var obj`, but the code still creates a jQuery object.

And without the variable, the function does not close over the object, therefore not creating a circular reference. Anyway, jQuery had fixed this issue by a workaround for those ancient browsers in which the DOM element didn't directly reference the handler.

Comment: Thank you, that puts my mind at ease! Especially the second part is helpful

Comment: With regards to your comment about the date of the article.. I wouldn't put it past Microsoft to keep a flaw like this in IE just 'cause they're thick, and actually get away with it, no?:)

Comment: No they arent "dead for a long time". IE11 and the horrors of IE still exist. Corporate kills. Memory leaks with circular references are still alive and kicking

Comment: @CotyEmbry The IE6/IE7 memory leak bug [was fixed with IE8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/dd361842(v=vs.85)).